# Can somebody help me break down and understand this collatz sequence code?

Tags: python

I'm a brand new programming graduate student and am having a bit of trouble. I'm working through a textbook problem that wants me to take a positive integer and print the Collatz sequence of that number.

```
    while num !=1:
        print(num)
        if num%2==0:
            num = num//2
    else:
        num = 3*num+1
print(1)
```

Now, this code works. And I get the mathematical logic. But there's parts I don't understand.

Firstly, the print(num), this is done so the code prints the input number since that starts the sequence. But, what is the logic/explanation to having this at the front of the loop?

Second, for num = num//2 and num = 3*num+1, why is that all you need for the code to run? In the end, our goal is to print the whole sequence until the input gets to 1. I thought you'd need an accumulator up top. i.e. lst = [] to append each value into that list and then return the list. Why does just re-labeling them num = work? Each time it iterates, wouldn't the prior value be deleted since it isn't stored anywhere?

Lastly, why do we not need to end the loop with a return? How does it know to print the whole sequence of numbers? It ends with print(1) because every input needs to end with that, and it terminates before 1. However, I have not called upon the function (it's a function on my end, not just a while loop) to take action. It just...did it.

I'm sorry if that's a bit confusing, but I'm trying to understand the correct code answer. I've mostly been doing accumulators and stuff, so I'm not sure why this didn't need one, what the num = did, and how you can just end it with print(1) and the whole sequence appears.

Comment: 2nd collatz question in the last few hours o.O ...

Comment: Wow, an "explain this code" question that actually gives us a detailed explanation of what you don't understand about the code. That's really rare!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Firstly, the print(num), this is done so the code prints the input number since that starts the sequence. But, what is the logic/explanation to having this at the front of the loop?

It's placed where it is because it's *not* just there to print the input number. It's there to print whatever `num` happens to be at that point in the code, *each time* that point in the code is reached. On the first iteration, `num` is the first element of the sequence. On the second iteration, `num` is now the second element of the sequence. On the third iteration, `num` is the third element, and so on. This `print` prints every element of the sequence, except `1`, because the loop breaks at that point, which is why there's a separate `print(1)` after the loop.

> Second, for num = num//2 and num = 3*num+1, why is that all you need for the code to run? In the end, our goal is to print the whole sequence until the input gets to 1. I thought you'd need an accumulator up top. i.e. lst = [] to append each value into that list and then return the list. Why does just re-labeling them num = work? Each time it iterates, wouldn't the prior value be deleted since it isn't stored anywhere?

`print(num)` prints each sequence element as it's computed, so the program doesn't need to explicitly save the elements. The program *does* forget the previous values, but they were already printed. Remembering the printed output is some other tool's job - for example, if you run this with stdout directed to a file, the printed output is written into the file.

> Lastly, why do we not need to end the loop with a return? How does it know to print the whole sequence of numbers? It ends with print(1) because every input needs to end with that, and it terminates before 1. However, I have not called upon the function (it's a function on my end, not just a while loop) to take action. It just...did it.

`return` has two jobs: it ends the current function execution, and it sets the return value. If execution reaches the end of a function without executing a `return`, execution of the function still ends, with a return value of `None`. `return` isn't involved in printing the output. That's `print`'s job, as explained above.

As for not calling the function, we can't answer what's going on with that. We would need to see what you actually ran, including the actual function.

Comment: dang nice novel ... :) +1

Comment: This was a tremendous breakdown - thank you! I see it more clearly now. It is constantly iterating and the new num goes through the cycle, as it is re-defined, and prints up top until you reach zero. My question is then - is this an efficient code to do this? I'm used to accumulators and appending to lists. For instance, having lst = [ ] up top and collecting values that way. Is this possible or less ideal here?

Comment: @ptoh64: Depends on what you want to do with the sequence elements. If all you wanted to do was print them, then printing and discarding them as you go is fine, and a list is unnecessary. If you wanted to save the sequence and do something else with it in the program, you can't just print and discard them.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica My only goal is to input a number and then print the sequence until we reach 1. I have also tried just messing with it and making a numlst = [ ] just to see and it makes no difference in my code, so it seems like adding it for the sense of this would be pointless. Super appreciate the help. I'm brand new to coding the answers make so much sense, but I have trouble thinking of these things myself..

Answer (score 0):

1. this is how the output "magically appears" without a list
2. see #1
3. you always return from a function ... in this case you are returning None, instead you are printing the list

it might help to put a `time.sleep` in there(inside your loop) to visualize whats happening

this site : [python tutor - see how it works](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20collatz%28num%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20while%20num%20!%3D1%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28num%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20num%252%3D%3D0%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20num%20%3D%20num//2%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20num%20%3D%203*num%2B1%0A%20%20%20%20print%28num%29%20%23%20same%20as%20print%281%29%20since%20num%20is%20by%20definition%20now%201%0A%20%20%20%20%0Acollatz%285%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20&cumulative=false&curInstr=6&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

is helpful for visualizing code execution

Comment: Wait, so no matter what - if we put return or not at the end of a function, it automatically returns? I'm also still wondering what the num = means for both of the math portions of the equation. Is it that you are re-defining num as the new number and then reiterating until you meet the condition? And lastly, is there a way to use an accumulator and append it like a list?

Comment: sure ... just append to the list everywhere you see a print ... and then return it ... and yes it redefines num until num becomes zero... click the link and step through the code on the site you will understand after a few times

Comment: Thank you so much! Being brand new, I need this stuff talked to me like I'm a baby haha. That website will help a lot. I sort of get discouraged at times. I come from a non STEM background so these beginner questions can keep me stumped for hours. Can be tough on the confidence so this helps.